# How to reload express.js or socket.io separately?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, sockets, socket.io

I'm using socket.io and express.js to build a website with virtual chat,
What I want to make is the option to let me choose when I want to reload socket.io and when I want to reload express.js.

Basically when I'm using express.js and socket.io in the same app.js file then whenever I reload the server, socket.io and express.js will be turned off and on, so everytime I just want to make some changes in the server side of the website I'll also need to reload the socket.io, which is not what I want.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: There is no way to do that built into nodejs.  It does not have the ability to unload code or reload part of your code to a new version without restarting the server.  Note, you socket.io clients should automatically reconnect so it's just up to your server code to maintain any state when it is restarted.

Comment: Another possibility would be to make your Express server and your socket.io server be separate servers (on separate ports).  Then, you could restart them separately.

Comment: You'd likely get this kind of functionality with use of Docker but it is out of scope for this question